# Is it possible to create a shared object using only as and ld?

Tags: shared-libraries, ld, gnu-assembler

I haven't been able to find information adequate for creating shared objects in assembly using as and ld.

I want to make a shared library containing some functions with variables (.data section). But ld won't accept the -shared option, when I have a .data segment in my code. (relocation R_X86_64_32S against '.data' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC). Surely it must be possible to use local variables in shared object code, but I can't find information on how to do it without compiling C-code with -fPIC option.

```
my_lib.s:

.globl print_info

.data
    output:
        .ascii "The processor vendor ID is 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'\n"

.bss

.text
    print_info:
        xor %eax, %eax
        cpuid
        movq $output, %rdi
        movl %ebx, 28(%rdi)
        movl %edx, 32(%rdi)
        movl %ecx, 36(%rdi)
        movl $1, %eax
        movl $1, %edi
        movq $output, %rsi
        movl $42, %edx
        ret
```

```
caller.s:

.globl _start

.data

.bss

.text
    _start:
        # some code to load shared library
        # with open() and mmap() syscalls

        subq $8, %rsp         # align stack
        call print_info
        addq $8, %rsp

        # some code here

        movl $60, %eax        # exit program
        xor %edi, %edi
        syscall
```

```
as my_lib.s -omy_lib.o
as caller.s -ocaller.o
```

produces no errors. However

```
ld -shared my_lib.o
```

presents:

```
ld: my_lib.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.data' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
ld: final link failed: nonrepresentable section on output
```

All the information on the subject I have been able to find, uses C-code and gcc for compiling and linking. Can anyone show how to go about it without coding in C and using gcc?

Answer (score 0):

Your assembly is not position-independent. In particular this:

```
movq $output, %rdi
```

should become

```
movq $output(%rip), %rdi
```

As a general recipe, I suggest to compile equivalent code in C (with `-fPIC`) and then examine the generated asm for necessary syntaxes.

Answer (score 0):

As yugr noted above, the shared object must be written with position-independent code. Using libdl.so to dynamically load the function from the lib [using open() and mmap() syscalls must come at a later time], I got it all working with:

```
lib.s: 

.globl print_info

.data
    output:
        .ascii "The processor vendor ID is 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'\n"

.bss

.text
    print_info:
        xor %eax, %eax
        cpuid
        leaq output(%rip), %rdi
        movl %ebx, 28(%rdi)
        movl %edx, 32(%rdi)
        movl %ecx, 36(%rdi)
        movl $1, %eax
        movl $1, %edi
        leaq output(%rip), %rsi
        movl $42, %edx
        syscall
        ret
```

```
assemble and link with:

as -olib.o lib.s
ld -shared -olib.so lib.o
rm lib.o
```

```
caller.s:

.globl _start

.data
    so_name:
        .asciz "./lib.so"
    func_name:
        .asciz "print_info"

.bss
    .lcomm handle, 8
    .lcomm func, 8

.text
    _start:
        movq $so_name, %rdi
        movl $1, %esi        # RTLD_LAZY == 1
        call dlopen

        movq %rax, handle
        movq %rax, %rdi
        movq $func_name, %rsi
        call dlsym

        movq %rax, func      # Not really necessary here, as func is used
                             # immediately and just this once
        call *%rax

        movq handle, %rdi
        call dlclose

        movl $60, %eax
        xorl %edi, %edi
        syscall
```

```
assemble and link with:

as -ocaller.o caller.s
ld -dynamic-linker /usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -ocaller caller.o -ldl
rm caller.o
```

Now you can run caller with:

```
./caller
```

The stack seems to be correctly aligned when using _start as entry (as opposed to using main, which apparently causes initial misalignment by pushing %rbp before calling main = your program), so there's no need to adjust by

```
subq $8, %rsp
```

before call and

```
addq $8, %rsp
```

after. At least so it seems, but I may be wrong on this point.